# Sending info when the user is typing (chatting)?

Tags: php, ios

I was wondering how could you implement or the logic if you like, sending the other user that the person their chatting to is typing something, I know it something to do the chat textfield being empty or not, but I just wanted to kind of clarify!

p.s. I'm trying to do this on an iPhone app and using a PHP language when communicating with an API!

Comment: Please tone down with the exclamation points _!!!_ It looks like you're shouting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSNotificationCenter should help you out on this. Read up on that and notifications. You would be able to detect keyboard events using that and hence work your logic out based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351266/no-events-such-as-editing-did-change-for-a-nstextfield) question on detecting the change event for an NSTextField.